# NSUserDefaults vs NSCoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

When saving small amounts of data from within my App is it better to use `NSUserDefaults` or `NSCoding`?
Right now I use `NSCoding` (encodeWithCoder/initWithCoder, etc.) but it appears that `NSUserDefaults` might be simpler.
My total data is about a variety of Ints/Strings/MutableArray, only about a few dozen total.

Comment: You're comparing apples with oranges. You might use NSCoding to save something into NSUserDefaults, so what contrast are you trying to draw?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is `NSPropertyListSerialization`.

Comment: To further was matt stated, NSCoding is not a storage mechanism at all. What are you doing with your encoded data? That is what you should compare against using NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that by `NSCoding` you mean "saving objects to files after serializing them with `NSCoding` APIs". Although both approaches are valid for primitive data types, the `NSUserDefaults` approach gets more difficult once you start serializing objects with complex structures.

In contrast, saving data of `NSCoding` classes to files offers high degree of flexibility in terms of object structure. If you know that you are not going to need this flexibility in the future, go with `NSUserDefaults`; if you are not sure, stay with the files.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct (my question should have been stated clearer). I'll stick with the NSCoding/file method since it's already working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is my preference to use a plist file that is programmatically created

```
NSString *appFile;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile"];
    //this creates the file path


    NSDictionary* tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:appFile];
    //this gets the data from storage

    [tempDict writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
    //this updates the data to storage
```